# .htaccess to fake subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I have a requirement where in I want to give users of my site their personal url.
Something like "http://abc.example.com" and when any user types this url in browser it should open this link "http://www.example.com/index/sub-domain?username=abc"
So I tried writing and trying many codes and finally was successful with below code but problem is it redirects. I want an internal redirection. URL address window should remain as "http://abc.example.com".

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index/sub-domain?username=%1
</IfModule>
```

I am not sure if It is possible or not ? Any advice or help will be of great help. Also can anyone suggest me some .htaccess tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specificy the R flag on your RewriteRule, mod_rewrite normally performs an internal rewrite. However, since you are using an absolute URL as your rewrite target, it has to be the exact same host, otherwise an external redirect will be issued.

If you really wish to internally redirect to another host, you should check out mod_proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but would be great if you can make me understand more. For eg: my main url for website is "www.mydomain.com" and to paid users I want to give a facility of personal URL, something like "abc.mydomain.com" and i want to execute this url "www.mydomain.com/xcontroller/yaction?username=abc" which atpresent display personal page of a user. How this thing will be achieved ??? Checking out mod_proxy as you suggested but any other help will be greatly appreciated ....